# class java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to class org.reactivestreams.Publisher

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I am try to create a unit test using Junit and Mockito. However I am getting an error saying

```
class java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to class org.reactivestreams.Publisher
```

When the it clearly returns a list of strings.

test

```
@Test
public void fullLoad() {
    when((Publisher<?>) this.mockedProductComponent.getErpNumbers("US", "es")).thenReturn(
        just(new ArrayList<>())
    );
}
```

method being tested

```
public boolean fullLoad(String country, String language) {

        List<String> erpNumbers = productComponent.getErpNumbers(country, language);
        log.info("Retrieved following ERP numbers: {}", erpNumbers);

        Lists.partition(erpNumbers, batchSize)
            .forEach(handleBatch(country, language));
        return true;
    }
```

method trying to mock

```
public List<String> getOnlineErpNumbers(String country, String lang) {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .scheme(scheme)
                .host(host)
                .path(path)
                .port(port)
                .pathSegment(country)
                .pathSegment(lang)
                .pathSegment("erp")
                .build())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>(){})
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
            .onErrorReturn(Collections.emptyList())
            .block();
    }
```

I know it must be because I am doing this the reactive way but I have not been able to find documentation on how to test such a process.

Comment: Why are you casting the result to (Publisher<?>) the method returns List<String>

Comment: @SimonMartinelli IDEA suggested it. without it I have an error

Comment: @SimonMartinelli when I remove it I get `Cannot resolve method 'when(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)'`

Comment: Why are you returning `just(list)`? You should be doing `when(mockedProductComponent.getErpNumbers("US", "es")).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confused your imports.

You are using [Mono.when](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#when-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) from Reactor which accepts a publisher:

```
public static Mono<Void> when(Publisher<?>... sources)
```

instead of [Mockito.when](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when-T-)

```
public static <T> OngoingStubbing<T> when(T methodCall)
```